# Error while deploying Friendly pix web app

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, lint

I am getting the following error while deploying the Friendlypix web app :

> npm ERR! missing script: lint
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR! C:\Users\Monika\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-04-05T00_40_57_180Z-debug.log
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1

I also tried installing eslint but it was of no help. How do I rectify this error or is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

check your package.json, you might have missed lint under scripts, but used it while deploying.

Comment: I had missed one step and now I have solved the issue. Thanks